# Getting the segmentation fault error while running yum command

Tags: memory, segmentation-fault

Getting the below error in /var/log/messages file while trying to run yum on centOS-5.5 64 bit server.

> kernel: yum[4467]: segfault at 0000000700001c4f rip 0000003747879a6a rsp 00007fffaf399cd8 error 4

and on CLI getting segmation fault error. Yum exits after giving that error.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

The depsolving algorithms in yum can use quite a bit of memory, possibly hitting RAM which isn't normally touched, exposing hardware issues you didn't know where there.

First thing to do is rule out memory problems — try [memtest86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86).

Comment: It was a bad configuration of one repo..

Comment: What was the bad configuration?